# How to use android:Theme.Material and Toolbar together?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

I am creating a android application where I am using Material Design components.I have used Material design theme(android:Theme.Material ), by extending my style with **android:Theme.Material**.

```
<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/navigationBarColor</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">disableHome</item>
</style>
```

Now, the issue is that I want to use toolbar also, but as I followed many tutorial I need to have **Theme.AppCompat** as my parent theme, if I want to use Toolbar.

I tried with Material Design Theme, but throwing me the error as

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity
```

So, my question is, I can't use Material Design theme with Toolbar(as I am using Card Views also, so Material Design Theme is preferable) ?

Note:-I haveintegrated Toolbar using **AppCompact** theme, but I want to use Material Design theme only.

Answer (score 3):

Set parent to "@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" and use AppCompatActivity in your activity.

Comment: I haveintegrated Toolbar using AppCompact theme, but I want to use Material Design theme only.

Comment: Ok then use this parent: "@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"

Answer (score 1):

You're getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity
```

because your `Activity` extends from `AppCompatActivity` and to use it is mandatory that your activity theme must have a Theme.AppCompat or descendant.

You could use `Toolbar` in your activity without extending from `AppCompatActivity` like this [post](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/how-to-add-toolbar-to-an-activity-which-doesn-t-extend-appcompatactivity-a07c026717b3#.qqdv0yjnb) refer. But you still need a `Theme.AppCompat` descendant.

BTW. Why do you need specifically `android:Theme.Material`?

Comment: I want to apply all the features of Material Design, that is why I am using Material Theme

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the theme in your manifest.

Edit your theme entry to look like this:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
```